# Need to increment date value of a specific field on webpage for every thread, not for loop count

Tags: jmeter

```
User Defined Variable: Date1

Thread Group Detail: 
Number of Threads: 100,
Ramp-Up Period: 100,
Loop Count: 1,

Http Request Name: SaveFlowSheet,
Parameter Name / Value: dttxtCurrentTreatmentDate / ${DATE1}.
```

I need to increment this parameter 'dttxtCurrentTreatmentDate' for every thread, not for loop count.

For this I added BeanShellPreprocessor as a child sample and added script mentioned in code section.

Here I found that date is getting increasing only one time.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; // necessary
import java.util.Calendar; // imports
import java.util.Date;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
Date date1 = sdf.parse(vars.get("DATE1")); // get DATE1 from UDV 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // get Calendar instance
cal.setTime(date1); // set Calendar's time to be DATE1
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1); // add 1 day to DATE1
date1 = cal.getTime(); // set the new value for date1
vars.put("DATE1",sdf.format(date1)); // update DATE1 JMeter variable
log.info("DATE1=" + vars.get("DATE1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I updated my code to:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; // necessary
import java.util.Calendar; // imports
import java.util.Date;
int threadNo = ctx.getThreadNum()+1;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
Date date1 = sdf.parse(vars.get("DATE1")); // get DATE1 from UDV 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // get Calendar instance
cal.setTime(date1); // set Calendar's time to be DATE1
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,threadNo); // add 1 day to DATE1
date1 = cal.getTime(); // set the new value for date1
vars.put("DATE1",sdf.format(date1)); // update DATE1 JMeter variable
log.info("DATE1=" + vars.get("DATE1"));
```

It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) user manual chapter:

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So if you need to increment the "global" variable you need to convert it to JMeter Property first like:

```
props.put("DATE1", vars.get("DATE1"));
```

and operate the `props` object, not the `vars` object going forward as variables which live under `vars` are [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Also I would recommend reconsidering using Beanshell as since JMeter 3.1 the users are encouraged to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) language, you will be able to shorten your code to be as simple as:

```
def date1 = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', props.get('DATE1'))
props.put('DATE1', date1.plus(1).format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)